# Obtain list of items related from many to many relationship entity vb

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Apologies if this is on here already.  Im new to coding with linq and entity framework in vb.

I have 3 tables.  Account table, User table with user_id row and a junction table to map the user_id to the account_id.

I want to get a list of accounts that belong to a user_id using linq and entity framework in vb.

```
dim findid = 1
return context.Accounts.Where(Function(m) m.Users.Any(Function(x) context.Users.Contains(findid)).tolist
```

Hope you can help, its driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim findid = 1
return context.Accounts
    .Where(Function(m) m.Users.Any(Function(x) x.user_id = findid)).ToList()
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the quick reply, just what i am after.  My first post as would have voted you up.